# How long does it take for item chests to respawn?

Tags: rust

Yesterday i bought Rust and played it for a few hours or so with some friends. We build a base near a town and near many resource nodes (since that seemed the logical thing to do). We looted the village and proceeded to gather resources. When we came back (about 45 minutes later) most of the chests had re-spawned already (so we looted them again). Now we got to a stage where we could build weaponry so we made some weapons, hunted some mutated animals and passed through the village and to our delight some of the chests had respawned again (barely 15 minutes). My question would be, what is the respawn time on loot chests/bags/etc in Rust. Does it ever vary or does it stay the same?

I know for a fact that the spawning of resources depends on the amount of players currently online (or active) in a certain area. Does this affect the chests as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The respawn timer on item crates ranges from 2 to 8 minutes, the respawn rate for all crates is somewhere in between those values I have seen crates respawn fairly quickly myself, so it shouldn't take that long to find some crates in the area you just passed through when for example hunting or resource gathering for a while. The amount of players in an area does not affect the respawn time on crates as the timers are set to their despawning after being looted.

Hope to have informed you well enough

**Edit:**
Added Youtube video link and reddit post explaining the crates and approximate respawn time.
Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEEly5uUwac) explaining several things about crates.
The poster of this video tells us the following:

> I tested it myself about 40 times and found it takes an average of 5 minutes for crates to respawn, they can take up to 9 minutes but they can often take 2 so don't go too far.

He also goes on explaining what the possible loot is for the different types of crates.

[Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/playrust/comments/1xp2fc/how_long_does_it_take_for_crates_to_respawn/)

> It's random, one time i grabbed a crate, it disappeared, then a second later it spawned again. I also find that the weapon crate seem to spawn faster than the other ones. But yeah somewhere between 5-10 minutes is about right.

**Edit 2:** As per request I have added my last comment in the answer as well since it clears up some of the things explained above.

> Yes it would I've seen resource nodes respawn in front of me as well as crates. As of yet crates as well as resource nodes are tied to respawn timers not to people roaming the area. These timers are started as soon as the item is despawned, the only difference between crates and nodes is that crates have a fixed spawn location and nodes do not

Comment: interesting, do you have any facts (sources / proof) about the 2 - 8 min respawn times? Also does the range vary for each chest? So does a wooden chest respawn every 2 mins while a yellow one re-spawns every 8 minutes?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include personal experience, sources and quotes.

Comment: So technically spoken. Waiting for 10 minutes IN the actual area would still cause the chests to respawn?

Comment: Yes it would I've seen resource nodes respawn in front of me as well as crates. As of yet crates as well as resource nodes are tied to respawn timers not to people roaming the area. These timers are started as soon as the item is despawned, the only difference between crates and nodes is that crates have a fixed spawn location and nodes do not.